# Bootstrap 3 - Add an asterisk to the input on the same row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried with:

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal form-article" role="form" data-ng-submit="save()">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required="required" data-ng-model="article.title">
                </div>
                <span>*</span>
            </div>
</form>
```

and

```
.form-article .form-group div:after {
    color: red;
    content: '*';
}
```

but the result is always

[image: how is the layout]

with like:

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal form-article" role="form" data-ng-submit="save()">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required="required" data-ng-model="article.title">
                </div>
                <span class="col-md-2">*</span>
            </div>
</form>
```

but the result is very ugly :(

Comment: Where in the input do you want it - do you mean just after title like 'Title*'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/4910/)

Try using:

```
.form-group div{
    position:relative;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.form-group div:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'*';
    color:red;
    right:-10px;
    top:0;
}
```

nb. You also hadnt closed one of your div tags in your posted code.

Comment: I removed `margin-right`. Otherwise, the input-field is a bit clinched. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a CSS class

```
.required-field:after {
    color: #d00;
    content: "*";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Use it just the label which is required

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="EmployeeName" class="control-label required-field col-sm-2">Employee Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "Employee.EmployeeName", alpha_numeric = "", required = "true" })
  </div>
  <label for="" class="control-label required-field col-sm-2">Birth Date</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "Employee.BirthDate", required = "true" })
  </div>
```